# Playing two separate animations one after another upon completion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to play two animations one after another in unity (each animation is two separate paths for the main camera) and from my research I think I need to use the following:

```
    // Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    animation.PlayQueued("CameraMovement", QueueMode.PlayNow);
    animation.PlayQueued("SpaceSceneMovement", QueueMode.CompleteOthers);

}
```

However, with this code attached to my camera, my game still only plays the first path. I created the paths so that there should be half a second delay between the different paths. I have both animations in the animation component of my camera (see attached pics) and I'm stumped as to why this isn't working.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: I don't have time to write you a correct solution, but Update runs each frame, so you are starting the first one, queueing the second one, and on the next frame you play the first one with higher priority (playnow). This repeats indefinitely with each frame meaning only the first animation will ever play.

If this is a one off perhaps move the code to Start()

Comment: Tried that but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by user2025312, you are calling the code each frame. Which means that each frame you're telling it to play the first animation immediately, and you queue the second one. That won't work.

Depending on what you want to do you have several options. Say you want to continuously play the two animations in a loop. What you could do is:

```
void Update () {
    if (!animation.isPlaying)
    {
        animation.PlayQueued("CameraMovement", QueueMode.PlayNow);
        animation.PlayQueued("SpaceSceneMovement", QueueMode.CompleteOthers);
    }
}
```

As should be easy to follow, that checks whether or not there is an animation playing, and if not, it will queue the two, playing the first one immediately. That will work fine within `Update()`.

If however you're looking to play the animation sequence just once (or upon a trigger) place the two lines within `Start()` or a method of your choice.

```
void Start () {
    animation.PlayQueued("CameraMovement", QueueMode.PlayNow);
    animation.PlayQueued("SpaceSceneMovement", QueueMode.CompleteOthers);
}
```

That should work just fine. If not, verify that your animations work individually.

Comment: Thank you. This works. Turns out I also had "play automatically" ticked. I turned this off and it works fine now.